# selenium rc with cruise control - testng error message - could not instantiate 'test'

Tags: selenium-rc, cruisecontrol, testng

I'm currently trying to set up cruisecontrol to run my selenium test suite. Everything works fine until I run the build, I got the following message:

calling target(s) [execute-test] in build file C:\Project\src\build.xml

Entering C:\Project\src\build.xml...

Exiting C:\Project\src\build.xml.

task location="C:\Project\src\build.xml:30: " name="antcall" time="0 seconds"

target name="execute-test" time="0 seconds"

task location="C:\Project\src\build.xml:37: " name="testng" time="0 seconds"

Executing 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_06\jre\bin\java.exe' with arguments:
'-ea'
'-classpath'
'C:\testng;C:\testng\testng-5.9-jdk15.jar;C:\testng\commons-lang-2.0.jar;C:\testng\testng-5.9-jdk14.jar'
'org.testng.TestNG'
'@C:\DOCUME~1\SERVER~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\1\testng10509'

The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
not part of the command.

[Parser] Running:

C:\Project\src\TestSuite.xml

[TestRunner] Running the tests in 'testInpagePlacement' with parallel mode:false

[RunInfo] Adding method selector: org.testng.internal.XmlMethodSelector@9664a1 priority: 10

[ClassHelper] Could not instantiate testcase1: testcase1

[ClassHelper] Could not instantiate testcase1: testcase1

===============================================

[Smoke test]

[Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0]

===============================================

[org.testng.TestNGException:]

[Cannot find class in classpath: testcase1]

at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.getSupportClass(XmlClass.java:55)

at org.testng.internal.Utils.xmlClassesToClasses(Utils.java:79)

at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:289)

at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:235)

at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:197)

at org.testng.TestRunner.(TestRunner.java:141)

at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:488)

at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:250)

at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:204)

at org.testng.TestNG.createAndRunSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:877)

at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:842)

at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:751)

at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:914)

at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:887)

The tests failed.

This was run on a network server, I'd tested the testsuite.xml locally through intellij and everything works fine. I feel like this is a config issue with the network server, please let me know if my assumption is wrong and point me to the right direction to fix this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have your classes (tests & target classes) on the classpath.